# Restharp and WebAPI2 object into DTO is null

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api2, restsharp, dto

)

I have a problem with RestSharp, WebAPI 2 and complex model DTOs.

My DTO model show like this

```
public class UserSearchDTO {

    public Guid UserAccId {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public User User {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Logon {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public SearchParams SearchParams {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public UserSearchDTO() {
        UserAccId = Guid.Empty;
        User = null;
        Logon = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

My SearchParams object show like this:

```
    SearchParams sp = new SearchParams();
    sp.Lastname = "Foobar";
```

My request from client:

```
/*REST BEGIN*/
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:5887");
var request = new RestRequest("api/UserManager/GetUser", Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("SearchParams", sp);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK) {
    string error = string.Format("Error REST-RESPONSE. Stauscode: {0}, StatusDescription: {1}", response.StatusCode, response.StatusDescription);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(error);
    throw new HttpException(error);
}
var _responseData = new RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer().Deserialize < UserSearchDTO > (response);
/*REST END*/
```

WebAPI method

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("GetUser")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult>    GetCustomIdentityData([FromBody]GetUser data)
```

My call from client has arrived. data.SearchParams has a object but all parameters into this object are null.

Where is the problem?

Thx for help.
Nero

Comment: Try to serialize `sp` as json and pass it to your request.

Comment: I serialize my object with 
`"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject"` and pass it into my request:

`request.AddParameter("SearchParams", jsonFromSP, "application/json; charset=utf-8", ParameterType.RequestBody):`

but this will not work. I get the following error:

`"StatusCode: UnsupportedMediaType, Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8, Content-Length: 877)"`